# Is $E(Z_i(t_{i,j})\varepsilon_{i,j}\phi_k^2(t_{i,j}))=0$?

Tags: stochastic-processes, expected-value, projection

Let $X(t)$ be a Gaussian process with mean function $f(t) = E(X(t))$ and $Z(t)=X(t)-f(t)$ and $\Gamma(s,t)=Cov(X(s),X(t))$ is the covariance function of $X$. Then we observe $Y_{i,j}$ at times $t_{i,j}$, $1\leq i \leq n,1\leq j \leq m$ and that are of the form $Y_{i,j}= f(t_{i,j}) + Z_i(t_{i,j}) + \varepsilon_{i,j}$, where $X_i(t)$ are random independent realizations of the process $X(t)$. We assume that the errors $\varepsilon_{i,j}$ are independent across $i$ and $j$ with $E(\varepsilon_{i,j})=0$ and $E(\varepsilon_{i,j}^2)=\sigma_\varepsilon^2$ and $\varepsilon$ is independent of X. We also assume the following points:

- $f\in L^2([0,1],dt)$ and is bounded, $dt$ denotes the Lebesgue measure
- $\phi_1,\phi_2,..$ a family of basis functions that are orthonormal in $L^2$ and are uniformly bounded
- The paths of the $X(t)$ are $L^2$-functions almost sure
- The observations times $t_{i,j}$ are independent and uniformly distributed

Now my question:

Is $E(Z_i(t_{i,j})\varepsilon_{i,j}\phi_k^2(t_{i,j}))=0$?

I think i need to condition on $t_{i,j}$ first and then use the independence, right? It is not so clear to me to prove this formally correct.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the fact that $\epsilon_{i,j}$ is independent of everything implies $E[Z_i(t_i,j)\varepsilon_{i,j} \phi_k^2(t_{i,j})] = E[\varepsilon_{i,j}] E[Z_i(t_i,j) \phi_k^2(t_{i,j})] = 0$.

Comment: So it is not necessary to condition on $t_{i,j}$, right? Can i do the same for $E[f(t_{i,j})Z_i(t_{i,j})\phi_k^2(t_{i,j})]$ or $E[Z_i(t_{i,j})\phi_k(t_{i,j})Z_i(t_{i,l})\phi_k(t_{i,l})]$, with $j\not= l$?

Comment: Hm, I didn't see that $t_{i,j}$ was also a random variable.  As long as $\varepsilon_{i,j}$ is independent of $t_{i,j}$ it shouldn't be a problem.  Otherwise, I think you might need to go into a little bit more detail on the $\varepsilon$ process and how $t_{i,j}$ is generated.

Comment: The observation times $t_{i,j} \sim U(0,1)$ and are independent. The errors $\epsilon_{i,j}$ are indepentend $\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$ random variables. I study the paper of Bunea, Ivanescu and Wegkamp 2011 "Adaptive inference for the mean of a Gaussian process in functional data".

Comment: @wjc You need to be more precise when you say "are independent."  $t_{i,j}$ and $\varepsilon_{i,j}$ are independent _of what_?  Just independent of each other, or independent of everything else?

Comment: My comment above is the formulation of the paper. I think they are just independent of each other and not of everything. But, as I mentioned in my original post, $\varepsilon$ is also independent of $X(t)$.